# Stored procedure with cyrillic characters parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

I'm dealing with some language issues in my SQL Server version 12.0.1800.

I have a table Persons and a stored procedure to return all persons based upon a like condition on their names. Name column is of type NVARCHAR(50).

The procedure works fine with the english languages, however when executing it with cyrillic characters, I need to use an N in front for results.

Does not work:

```
exec GET_PERSONS @argName = 'тест'
```

Works:

```
exec GET_PERSONS @argName = N'тест'
```

Problem is that I use this procedure from a C# client with entity framework 6. and there is no way to put an N in front of a parameter what I know, and according to sources I shouldn't need to if columns are nvarchar.

Call to procedure (returns nothing):

```
string name = "тест";
db.SP_GetPersons(name);
```

Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PERSONS]
    @argName NVarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        name
    FROM
        Persons
    WHERE
        Name like ISNULL(@argName + '%', '%')
        or Name like concat('% ', @argName, '%')

END
```

Comment: is the space in this a typo or up.ProfileName like concat('% ',`

Comment: Nope, not a typo. However , the like condition is legit. If I hardcode @argName = N'тест', it return rows. Seems like Unicode is lost for the parameter

Comment: How is this call done? Is the SP complete as you show it (btw: SPs just to **read** data is like hammering nails with a beer bottle... Wrong tool...)? A string in C# is unicode, the input parameter is unicode. There is no reason to change this in the middle... I'm quite sure, that there is some other process involved...

Comment: The SP is a short example of the part that matters. I can agree on the read part, but in this case it makes sense. I've given multiple call examples, but the most important one (C#) is not returning results with cyrillic characters. I'll go ahead and make a native sql call and see if that helps

Comment: Same SQL query worked with cyrillic also when doing it with EF raw sql (db.DataBase.SqlQuery) so I'll do it that way instead. Seems like procedure parameters loses unicode somewhere on the way